# Localizing Windows Phone 7 App

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm having a little trouble getting localized resources files to work on  Windows Phone 7.  Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a resource file, say "Strings.resx" (Build Action: Compile)
2. Create a key, say "TestKey" with a default value of empty string
3. Add a English resource file in the same folder with a value of "some English string": Strings.en-us.resx (Build Action: Embedded Resource)
4. Add a Japanese resource file in the same folder with a value of "some Japanese string": Strings.ja-jp.resx (Build Action: Embedded Resource)

In my PC Silverlight, WPF Apps that works fine when I change the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.  But in the phone I always seem to be getting the value that's in the Strings.resx file - an empty string.

I have tried using the designer generated code and wiring up the resource manager by hand and it does not seem to matter.   Here's my code:

```
            Type t = typeof(Strings);

            _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(
                t.Namespace + "." + t.Name,
                t.Assembly);

            _resourceManager.GetString("TestKey");
```

Tell me localized resources are supported on the phone... ;>  What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Update**: Thanks Olivier for forwarding the link.  I saw that as well but missed an important step.  I didn't  add the "SupportedCultures" node to my csproj.  Made all the difference - hoping someone else doesn't loose two hours trying to figure this out like I did.

```
<SupportedCultures>de-DE;es-ES;</SupportedCultures>
```

Comment: +1 for `SupportedCultures` property. Surprising that's not exposed in Visual Studio via Application properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a blog post that provides links to a bunch of [Globalization / Localization guides for WP7.](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/09/localization-and-globalization-in-wp7.html) There is a [Windows Phone 7 in 7 Training video](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/Description.aspx?eventId=1883) that helped me understand the basics. After that it was simply a matter of learning how to do databinding:

> The MSDN article shows you how to
>   setup the files and create the
>   LocalizedStrings class, but they then
>   assume that you know how to use that
>   class for data binding. Visual Studio
>   2010 and Silverlight handle data
>   binding differently than Winforms, and
>   it gets even more confusing since XAML
>   also has it’s own definition of
>   Resources that are different then the
>   .NET resources we just created.
>   Silverlight also uses the term
>   Resource to refer to files that use
>   the the Build Action of "Content”, as
>   these files get wrapped up into the
>   .XAP file similar to how files with
>   Build Action of "Resource” get
>   embedded into the .Dll assembly (ex:
>   loading an image from content or
>   resource files). I found that instead
>   of using the Text="{Binding
>   Path=resourceFile.resourceName,
>   Source={StaticResource
>   Localizedresources }}" XAML syntax it
>   was easier to use the following steps:
>
> 1. Open your primary XAML page (usually MainPage.xaml) in the Visual
>      Studio designer
> 2. Open the properties for the PhoneApplicationPage and set the
>      DataContext to be
>      Application.Resources –>
>      LocalizedStrings. NOTE: if you already
>      are using a DataContext object, then
>      you should integrate the
>      LocalizedStrings class into that
>      object so that it has localization
>      support.
> 3. Once the Page’s DataContext has been set you can change the data
>      binding for any control on the page by
>      simply selecting the property (ex:
>      text, checked, etc), selecting “Apply
>      Data Binding…”, and setting the Path
>      to Localizedresources.BtnText or
>      whatever the name of the desired
>      resource value is.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 6):

Of course, localized resources are supported on the phone:

[How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)