# Windows 8 Metro app (XAML) - How to set a default startup language?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I try to set a default startup language in my Windows Metro app in App.xaml.cs, but I cannot find the place to do it. Usually I set this up using Thread.CurrentCulture in C#, but I cannot locate the Thread namespace. Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

This works great in Windows8 CP:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de";
var resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's still on demand I have an option here:

Try set up default App language in Package.appxmanifest. Open the manifest with VS and set default language in appropriate box (application UI -> default language).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set it on the project assembly. Try right click the project, then "Assembly Information..." and select your neutral culture.

Comment: UDPATE: I actually tried that, but the Metro App did not find the correct resource file. I have checked that I actually managed to set the culture in app.xaml.cs using the following code:             

//Setting Norwegian as default startup language even if the OS i English.
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("no");
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("no");

Comment: UPDATE: But still the English resource file is loading because my Windows 8 OS is installed in English it seems. I have defined the resources as described in this quick start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771181.aspx but with no luck. I also want the user to be able to change the language in runtime.

Comment: Any idea how to change language in C# Metro App during runtime to load the correct language resources?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. I haven't tried it on win8 but I guess it is using the same model as on WP7, that is, only the user defines the language. But you can define which cultures you accept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801119/localizing-windows-phone-7-app, maybe that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Default thread culture using CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting it in App.xaml.cs like shown below will help

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationPreferences.PreferredLanguage = "no";
```

Where "no" is BCP47 language tag for norwegian language.

**Update**: Metro app language change at runtime

According to Windows 8 SDK sample "Application resources and localization"

> It is possible that, while an application is running, the language, scale, contrast or other settings may change. In order to handle these events, event listeners should be registered to listen for and react to the change. This can be done either by storing state and refreshing the page or by redrawing specific resources.

Now in my language change selection event i'm setting the PreferredLanguage like:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationPreferences.PreferredLanguage = "en";
this.Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
```

And the key thing i've been missing is code below in App's OnLaunched event:

```
ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += async (s, m) => 
{
    if (m.Key == "Language")
    {
        // react to language change
    }
};
```

I didn't place this event registration in Page's construtor or any page's event (as it is in SDK sample) because then it could've been registered multiple times.
Still this event has to be registered somewhere for language change to take effect at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for (in the CP) is `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationPreferences.PreferredLanguage.`

Note that your manifest should list all of the languages you actually support. VS will set the languages for you automatically if the manifest in the project contains `x-generate`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the code view of your Package.appxmanifest
Change Resources to:

```
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
```